# I'm trying to make a batch file what is wrong with my code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a code where I can go to websites without going to my browser I have  atop search function which I will change manually I'm fairly new to coding so any advice is helpful here is the code.

```
@echo off
echo Top searches
echo 1. Faceit
set /p name =
if %name% EQU "1" goto F
if %name% NEQ "1" then goto custom

:F
start "" https://www.faceit.com/en


:custom
echo What website would you like to go to?
set /p x =
start "" https://www.%x%
```

Comment: I can see a whole lot of things (read: at least 10 things) wrong with your code. Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: @SomethingDark How do I properly make the equal to and not equal to commands work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit going on in your code that is keeping it from working in any meaningful sort of way. Just at an initial glance, I see ten separate things that are either completely wrong or simply violate what could be considered "good programming practices" in batch.

### 1/2. Whitespace in variable names is significant

For some reason, Microsoft decided to allow whitespace in variable names, so `%this is a valid variable name%`. Seriously. As a result of this, both of your `set /p` statements are creating variables that you never use.

Instead of `set /p name =` and `set /p x =`, use `set /p name=` and `set /p x=`

### 3/4. Put quotes around set statements

This one is just good programming practice and is arguably not "wrong," but it's a good habit to form early.

Use quotes to avoid the user entering things like `&` or `>` and having those break the flow of the script. You can put the quotes to the around the prompt (like `set /p variable="Enter text: "`), but if you do that with a regular `set` statement, the quotes will become part of the value. To avoid this, put the first quote to the left of the variable name, like this: `set /p "variable=Enter text: "`

This also prevents any hidden spaces from getting tacked on at the end of the value by accident.

### 5.   Then is not a keyword in batch

The `then` in your second `if` statement if going to give you a syntax error because it's not a valid keyword in batch. Just get rid of it.

```
if "%name%" NEQ "1" goto custom
```

### 6/7. Quotes in comparisons are significant

When you put quotes around one side of a comparison, you need to put quotes on the other side as well. This has the added effect of keeping characters like `&` and `>` from breaking the flow of the script.

```
if "%name%" EQU "1" goto F
if "%name%" NEQ "1" goto custom
```

### 8. A missing goto (or exit) will cause :custom to run immediately after :F

Batch scripts run from top to bottom unless acted upon by a `goto`, `call`, `if`, or some other flow control command. In this case, after `start "" https://www.faceit.com/en` is called, the very next non-whitespace line is `:custom`.

To avoid :custom from running, kill the script after the first start with `exit /b` or `goto :eof` - both of these will stop the script but keep the command prompt open if you ran the script from the command line instead of double-clicking it. Note that if you use `goto :eof`, you do **not** need to make a `:eof` label, since it's built into the command prompt.

### 9/10. Put colons in front of labels in goto commands

Again, not necessary, just good programming practice. You have to include the colons when you use `call` to run subroutines anyway, so you might as well be consistent everywhere.

## Other notes

- When the script is first run, all you see is

> Top searches
>   1. Faceit

and that's it. Nothing to tell the user what to do or to indicate that they can enter another site by typing something other than `1`. Unless you plan on being the only person to use the script, I'd recommend putting something somewhat more descriptive in that section.

- If you're going to automatically tack on `https://www.` to the start of a custom URL, put that on the screen so that the user doesn't accidentally end up going to `https://www.https://www.google.com` or something.
- You may want to look into the `choice` command for future versions of the script to replace the initial `set /p` command, depending on how many options you want to give the user.
- Putting comments in your code wouldn't hurt.

## Ultimately, it will look something like this

```
@echo off
echo Top searches
echo 1. Faceit
echo Enter anything else to go to a different site
set /p "name=Your selection: "
if "%name%" EQU "1" goto :F
if "%name%" NEQ "1" goto :custom

:F
start "" https://www.faceit.com/en
exit /b

:custom
echo What website would you like to go to?
set /p "x=https://www."
start "" https://www.%x%
```